# Javascript undefined var window.location

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a dynamic function that makes redirects but it doesn't work
It returns me 'undefined'

here is the HTML code:

```
<p>You will be redirected to the page X in <span id="time">4</span> seconds..</p>
```

here is the JavaScript code:

```
 var seconds;
 var temp;

 function countdown(page) {    
     seconds = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;
     seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10);
     if (seconds == 1) {
         temp = document.getElementById('time');
         temp.innerHTML = '0. If you are not, please click <a href="' + page + '">here</a>.';
         window.location = page;
         return;
     }
     seconds--;
     temp = document.getElementById('time');
     temp.innerHTML = seconds;
     timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
 }
 countdown('/asimplepage/asdfgh.html');
```

I tried also to do:

```
function redirect(page){
    window.location = page;
}
redirect('thisworks.html');
```

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Done, posted, see the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
 timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
```

When `setTimeout` invokes `countdown`, it is not passing the `page` parameter that originally kicks the function off. So, the second (and subsequent times) that `countdown` runs, nothing is being passed in for `page`.

Change the line to:

```
 timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(function(){countdown(page)}, 1000);
```

This instructs the `setTimeout()` function to schedule a call to the anonymous function, which in turn will call `countdown` and supply `countdown` with the `page` variable value, after one second.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped me

Comment: I think your jsfiddle link is wrong. You linked the homepage.

Comment: Yeah, strange. JSFiddle won't let me save it. Anyway, I did test this and it does correct the issue.